# How to use arrayformula with GCD?

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use this formula to determine if Column A is a multiple of 5, but the arrayformula isn't expanding.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(GCD(5,A1:A)=5,TRUE,FALSE))
```

`GCD` doesn't seem to support arrayformula. How to make it work with `ARRAYFORMULA`?

Column C is the result of using autofill.

| A | B[Arrayformula] | C[DragFill] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FALSE | FALSE |
| 2 |  | FALSE |
| 3 |  | FALSE |
| 4 |  | FALSE |
| 5 |  | TRUE |
| 6 |  | FALSE |
| 7 |  | FALSE |
| 8 |  | FALSE |
| 9 |  | FALSE |
| 10 |  | TRUE |
| 62 |  | FALSE |
| 34 |  | FALSE |
| 22 |  | FALSE |
| 75 |  | TRUE |
| 34 |  | FALSE |
| 46 |  | FALSE |
| 30 |  | TRUE |
| 21 |  | FALSE |
| 92 |  | FALSE |
| 56 |  | FALSE |

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. Your question may be closed, if it isn't self contained. Your table should be a minimal example.[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=BYROW(A1:A20, LAMBDA(x, GCD(5, x)=5))
```

[image]

or just:

```
=INDEX(MOD(A1:A20, 5)=0)
```

[image]